# How to get specific section form data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

To clearly defined the problem consider this example.

```
<form id='myform'>
    <div id='location'>
            <input type='text' name='username'>
    </div>
    <div id='background' style='display:none'>
            <input type='text' name='username'>
    </div>
    <div id='family' style='display:none'>
            <input type='text' name='username'>
    </div>
</form>
```

OK. Now what i am trying to do is create an edit form. First i am displaying each item of user data on a page. User data has been devided in sections like this

```
Location
VisualAppearance
Background
Family
EducationAndCareer
Lifestyle
AdditionalQuestions
```

Now for example location section contains some information about user location like

```
country , city , zip , state
```

Each item like country contains an arrow. On arrow click i send user to another page with a get parameter `?item=location`. on document ready i see what is in get and then fill the related fields and display the demanded section. Load the required dropdowns and seleted items in them. Now i want to post data with ajax. If i use `$('form').serialize()` it will send all the sections information with null values which i dont want. Because other sections are hidded and were not loaded. I want to send data only for location in this scanrio. How can i do this.

I am working for mobile . I am using jquery and knockout for this.

Comment: You could disable the `inputs` from the hidden `divs`. That way `.serialize()` won't add them

Comment: You could modify the data that you post with ajax in beforeSend event handler or in form.submit() event handler

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to collect all "visible" form elements with jQuery that don't have a specific class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969573/best-way-to-collect-all-visible-form-elements-with-jquery-that-dont-have-a-sp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let jQuery `serialize()` only part of the form using simple CSS selectors:

```
$('#location :input').serialize()
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYrqA/).

Comment: ok what if there are select , checkboxes and radio buttons. The code i posted is only sample

Comment: All included. `"The :input selector basically selects all form controls"`. see http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: Thanks @haim770 for this but this is not working although i have found a better solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select). I am checking this for giving me correct idea.